# Oracle 2.111.7.0 32 bit on Win7 64 bit machine

Tags: oracle, odp.net

I install Oracle 11gR2 32 bit client on my Win7 64 bit machine. its Oracle.DataAccess.dll's version is 2.111.7.0. When I run my code, I got this error message: 
Could not load file or assembly 'Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.111.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
What's the problem? Does it means, I cannot use this 32 bit on my Win7 64 bit machine, I have to install 64 bit version of it? Because 32 bit is our company policy to install on all my user's machine. It is hard to change it.

Thank you so much
Wes

Comment: 32-bit applications should work by default on 64-bit Windows; unless they've been explicitly disabled (in which case you'd have to enable it).

Comment: See this: http://www.alexjamesbrown.com/development/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-chilkatdotnet2-or-one-of-its-dependencies-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run the application in 32 bit mode and link it against this specific version in the first place, it works and you can use the 32 bit version on a 64 bit system.

To force an application to run in 32 bit mode, you have several options (partially depending on whethere it's a stand-alone application or web application), which are outline in this [article](http://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2009/10/21/force-net-application-to-run-in-32bit-process-on-64bit-os/).